# Wordpress WP_Query using filter, custom post types, and custom fields will not return correct post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to get results for certain post_types, however, when ever I add the filter to check if the post_title and post_content are "LIKE" the query string, all post_types are returned, including attachment post_types, which I do not want as show in the $args. Here is the code I am trying:

```
$query_string = get_search_query();
$args = array(                      
        'post_type' => array("hc_pillow", "hc_topper", "hc_accessory", "page"),                                                                                             
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                    'key' => 'tab_retail',
                'value' => $query_string,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'tab_tech',
                'value' => $query_string,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'tab_shipping_information',
                'value' => $query_string,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),                      
        'posts_per_page' => "-1"                        
);
function filter_where_title($where = '') {
    $query_string = get_search_query();
    $where .= " OR post_title LIKE '%".$query_string."%' OR post_content LIKE '%".$query_string."%'";                   
    return $where;
}
$posts = new WP_Query();
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where_title');
$posts->query($args);                
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where_title');
```

Any help at all would be appreciated, I'm not sure what else to try.,

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE statement should be structured like that:

```
WHERE `post_type` IN ( 'hc_pillow', 'hc_topper', 'hc_accessory', 'page' ) AND ( `post_title` LIKE '%search_string%' OR `post_content` LIKE '%search_string%' )
```

Now it's more like

```
WHERE `post_type` IN ( 'hc_pillow', 'hc_topper', 'hc_accessory', 'page' ) OR `post_title` LIKE '%search_string%' OR `post_content` LIKE '%search_string%'
```

where any single condition of the three would be enough to envalidate a row.